# C# .NET 4.7.2: Embed an outlook object as an email's attachment

Tags: c#, outlook, attachment, com-automation

I created a code that builds a html string being the body of an email. However, I want this email to be an attachment of my general and base email that I created in first place. The code below actually works but at the end of it, when I open my general email, I have the secondary email as attachment but when I click on it, the email attached is a blanck email. This outcome despite I created the html body. the html string just vanish at the end of the last method "AddMessageAsAttachment". Any help would be much appreciated... Thank you

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

foreach (var positionlist in result)
{
    string salesEmailAddress = positionlist.Key;

    //Create the general email to the salesman
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Application();
    MailItem generalMail = application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as MailItem;
    generalMail.Body = "Hello, Please find your quarterly reports";
    generalMail.Subject = $"Quarterly Report";
    generalMail.To = salesEmailAddress;

    foreach (DataRow row in positionlist)
    {
        MailItem mailToAdd = CreateSecondaryEmail(row, "EN", "P:/My_path/Report_EN.oft", @"P:\Another_path\SecondaryEmailAttachment.pdf");
        Globale.AddMessageAsAttachment(generalMail, mailToAdd);
    }

    private MailItem CreateSecondaryEmail(DataRow row, string lang, string template, string attachement)
    {
        string clientNumber = row["account_nbr"];
        string currency = row["Ccy"];

        html += $@"<html>
                    <div style='font-family: Haboro Contrast Ext Thin;font-size: 15,5'>
                        <p style=''></p><BR>
                        <span style=''>{clientNumber}</span><BR>
                        <span style=''> {currency}</span><BR>            
                    </div>";

        html += "</html>";
        MailItem mailPosition = Globale.CreateItemFromTemplate(html, email, template, factsheet);

        return mailPosition;
    }
}
```

"CreateItemFromTemplate" actually links from a template the body of the secondary email and a quick pdf report (parameter "attachement") that will be attached:

```
public static Outlook.MailItem CreateItemFromTemplate(string html, string emailaddress, string template, string attachement = null, string client_number = null)
    {

        Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MailItem mail = application.CreateItemFromTemplate(template) as Outlook.MailItem;
        mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody.Replace("#BODY", html);
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string date = $"Data as of  {dt.Day}.{dt.Month}.{dt.Year}";
        mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody.Replace("#DATE",date);
        mail.Subject = $"Quarterly Report of the client {client_number}";
        mail.To = emailaddress;
        if (attachement != null)
        {
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachement);
        }
        return mail;     
    }
```

Eventually, I created a "Globale" class with a method that will retrieve the secondary email (mailPosition) that is generated by the above "CreateItemFromTemplate" method and put it in the general email as an attachment.

```
public static void AddMessageAsAttachment(Outlook.MailItem mailContainer,Outlook.MailItem mailToAttach)
    {
        Outlook.Attachments attachments = null;
        Outlook.Attachment attachment = null;
        try
        {
            attachments = mailContainer.Attachments;
            attachment = attachments.Add(mailToAttach,
               Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 1, "The attached e-mail");
            mailContainer.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (attachment != null) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachment);
            if (attachments != null) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachments);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call the `Save` method after doing any modifications to any newly created items before attaching them.

Also there is no need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance in the code. For example, I've noticed the following code in the beginning of your post:

```
//Create the general email to the salesman
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Application();
    MailItem generalMail = application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as MailItem;
    generalMail.Body = "Hello, Please find your quarterly reports";
```

And in the `CreateItemFromTemplate` method I see:

```
Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mail = application.CreateItemFromTemplate(template) as Outlook.MailItem;
mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody.Replace("#BODY", html);
```

Finally, I'd suggest attaching web page instead of creating items and attaching them. The web page can be opened and viewed in Outlook.

Comment: Thank you Eugene, the Save method within the "CreateItemFromTemplate" method did the trick !
I actually made a new instance of Outlook application because CreateItemFromTemplate is within another class called "Globale".
I'll check also the web pages